# How to processing UI while looping?

Tags: android, media, audiorecord

I want process the UI element while lopping.
This code is recoding streaming audio.
But code have some issues.
Application stop in while instruction. So, "Record Button" don't change.
Also, Application can user actions.(button click, etc)
I want that button is clickable and writing data to file same time.
Following the code:

```
PlayerActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    btnStartStopRecord.setText(R.string.button_record_stop);
    try{
    conn = new("Streaming URL").openConnection();
    is = conn.getInputStream();
        outstream = new FileOutputStream(new File(dataDir, fileName).getAbsolutePath());

            int c;
    while((c = is.read()) != -1) {
         outstream.write(c);
    }
} catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
     error(e.toString());
    }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The application freezes because you're executing expensive operations on the UI thread.

You need to use background thread.

See:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html
- http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/

for reference.

Comment: I want change UI element and record the stream audio. Can you provide in detail code?